# complete vector field and diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I need a reference with a complete proof for the following theorem:

If $\{X_t;  t\in [0,T)\}$ is a continuous time-dependent family of vector fields on a compact manifold, then there exists a one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\{\varphi_t:M\to M; t\in [0,T)\}$, such that
$$\partial_t\varphi_t(x)=X_t(\varphi_t), \varphi_0=id,$$
for all $x\in M$ and $t\in [0,T).$

Comment: You might want to consider the vector field $Y = (X, 1)$ on $M \times I$; the flow for $Y$ will take $X \times \{0\}$ to $X \times \{t\}$ for every $t$, thus providing you with the diffeomorphisms you seek. But I don't know a book that writes out this proof (or any other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 4.3 [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/manifolds2012.pdf) I believe is what you are looking for. Of course, some earlier results are also needed.

Moreover, this topic is covered in various textbooks like:

1. Introduction to Smooth Manifolds - Lee
2. An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry - Boothby

Comment: Lee's chapter on flows (in particular he section on time dependent vector fields) is absolutely phenomenal